# What are my options for venting my oil boiler?

Tags: hvac, heating

I have a small New Yorker AP-U (480?) boiler that is currently vented to a large flu in my house's chimney. I want to install a wood stove in my house and I'd like to use the chimney to vent it, which means the furnace would not be able to use that flue. What options do I have for venting my furnace?

P.S. I have a chimney expert coming to take a look tomorrow. I'm just looking for other opinions.

Comment: You may be able to get more than one flu up the chimney. That depends on your specific situation.

Comment: Unfortunately I've only got 8x8 tile in the chimney. There's no room to separate it into two flues.

Comment: Im not an hvac expert but there is a new thing called direct vent. It uses a blower to cool the exhaust enough that it can vent through 3" PVC pipe right out the side of the house. Some might use a metal vent similar to a pellet stove or gas fireplace. I dont know if your unit can be converted but the cost of a new masonry chimney would be more than a new boiler with direct vent. A double walled Pipe might be similar in price but they look bad on the side of a house.

Comment: Depends on the architectural style, but I've found stainless or matte-black pipes can look quite nice as an interior feature (especially in tall rooms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're installing the wood stove new, why bother running it through the existing chimney? Just run new chimney pipe from the stove through the roof (added bonus that the exposed chimney pipe will radiate more heat to the room).

Comment: Interesting... I hadn't thought of that. One of the reasons I wanted to use the chimney for the stove is so that the chimney would function as a thermal mass, but the stove pipe radiating heat would be a bonus as well.

Answer (score 0):

The present through the wall vents on furnaces have a problem..as a safety feature when snow accumulates around exhaust the furnaces shuts down...Great concept, however maritime winters will find you out shoveling snow away from vents on a regular basis especially the winter of 2014/15..